# Need to get my host Ubuntu machine in the same network as the containers

Tags: networking, ubuntu, docker, container

I am trying to play around with networking using Python and one of the best resources I could find was [here - Brandon Rhodes](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/fopnp/tree/m/playground)

Now I have taken the approach of using the vagrant file provided in the above and the default virtual box image included in it. Everything seems to be working perfectly fine here.

So essentially, I am able to get the ubuntu box up and running that has the below architecture (taken from the link above)

[image]

From my Ubuntu machine I am able to perfectly ssh into h1, h2, h3 and h4 boxes and from there into any of the other boxes in the given infrastructure as well.

However, I am very new to the concept of containers (Docker and it's configurations in this case) and am just starting to explore it. So please bear with my ignorance here. And hence, I do not really totally understand how exactly is the entire network configuration of the containers done in the above case.

I am able to make some sense from the launch.sh script and the Docker files again from the github link above, but not completely.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Start up the network playground on a boot2docker instance, assuming
# that "build.sh" has already been run in this directory to build the
# Docker images..

set -e -x
cd $(dirname "$0")

# If Docker has just been installed, we might need to join its group.

if ! echo "$(groups)" | grep -q docker
then
    sudo adduser vagrant docker
    exec newgrp docker < ./launch.sh
fi

# Make sure network tools are ready to run.

if [ ! -x /sbin/brctl ]
then
    sudo apt-get -y install bridge-utils
fi
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/netns
sudo modprobe ip_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_ftp

# Tool to start a container.

start_container () {
    hostname=$1
    image=$2
    port=$3
    container=${hostname%%.*}

    pid=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' $container 2>/dev/null || true)

    if [ "$pid" = "" ]
    then
        if [ -n "$port" ]
        then netopts="--publish=$port:22"
        else netopts="--net=none"
        fi
        docker run --name=$container --hostname=$hostname \
            --dns=10.1.1.1 --dns-search=example.com "$netopts" \
            --volume=$(readlink -f ..):/fopnp -d $image
    elif [ "$pid" = "0" ]
    then
        docker start $container  >/dev/null
    else
        return
    fi

    pid=$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' $container)
    sudo rm -f /var/run/netns/$container
    sudo ln -s /proc/$pid/ns/net /var/run/netns/$container

    echo Container started: $container
}

# These commands are each a no-op if the command has already run.

start_bridge () {               # args: BRIDGE_NAME
    sudo brctl addbr $1 &>/dev/null || return
    sudo ip link set $1 up
    echo Created bridge: $1
}
give_interface_to_container () { # args: OLD_NAME CONTAINER NEW_NAME
    sudo ip link set $1 netns $2
    sudo ip netns exec $2 ip link set dev $1 name $3
    sudo ip netns exec $2 ip link set $3 up
}
create_interface () {
    #
    # Given an interface name "www-eth0", create both an interface with
    # that name and also a peer that is connected to it.  Place the peer
    # in the container "www" and give it the name "eth0" there.
    #
    interface=$1
    container=${interface%%-*}
    short_name=${interface##*-}
    sudo ip link add $interface type veth peer name P &>/dev/null || return
    give_interface_to_container P $container $short_name
    echo Created interface: $interface
}
create_point_to_point () {
    #
    # Given arguments "backbone eth0 isp eth1", create a pair of peer
    # interfaces and put one inside the container "backbone" and name it
    # "eth0" and the other inside of "isp" with the name "eth1".
    #
    sudo ip netns exec $1 ip link set $2 up &>/dev/null && return
    sudo ip link add P type veth peer name Q
    give_interface_to_container P $1 $2
    give_interface_to_container Q $3 $4
    echo Created link between: $1 $3
}
bridge_add_interface () {
    bridge=$1
    interface=$2
    sudo brctl addif $bridge $interface &>/dev/null || return
    sudo ip link set dev $interface up
    echo Bridged interface: $interface
}

# Build the playground.

start_container h1 fopnp/base 2201
start_container h2 fopnp/base 2202
start_container h3 fopnp/base 2203
start_container h4 fopnp/base 2204
start_container modemA fopnp/base
start_container modemB fopnp/base
start_container isp fopnp/base
start_container backbone fopnp/dns
start_container example.com fopnp/base
start_container ftp.example.com fopnp/ftp
start_container mail.example.com fopnp/mail
start_container www.example.com fopnp/www

# For each LAN, create an ethernet bridge and corresponding interfaces.

create_interface h1-eth1
create_interface h2-eth1
create_interface h3-eth1
create_interface h4-eth1
create_interface modemA-eth1
create_interface modemB-eth1

start_bridge homeA

bridge_add_interface homeA modemA-eth1
bridge_add_interface homeA h1-eth1
bridge_add_interface homeA h2-eth1
bridge_add_interface homeA h3-eth1

start_bridge homeB

bridge_add_interface homeB modemB-eth1
bridge_add_interface homeB h4-eth1

create_interface example-eth1
create_interface ftp-eth0
create_interface mail-eth0
create_interface www-eth0

start_bridge exampleCOM

bridge_add_interface exampleCOM example-eth1
bridge_add_interface exampleCOM ftp-eth0
bridge_add_interface exampleCOM mail-eth0
bridge_add_interface exampleCOM www-eth0

# The other network connections are simple point-to-point links.

create_point_to_point backbone eth0 isp eth0
create_point_to_point backbone eth1 example eth0
create_point_to_point isp eth1 modemA eth0
create_point_to_point isp eth2 modemB eth0

# Configure manual IP addresses and routes on the point-to-points.
# First, down in the direction of the broadband modems.

sudo ip netns exec backbone ip addr add 10.1.1.1/32 dev eth0
sudo ip netns exec backbone ip route add 10.25.1.1/32 dev eth0
sudo ip netns exec backbone ip route add 10.25.0.0/16 via 10.25.1.1

sudo ip netns exec isp ip addr add 10.25.1.1/32 dev eth0
sudo ip netns exec isp ip addr add 10.25.1.1/32 dev eth1
sudo ip netns exec isp ip addr add 10.25.1.1/32 dev eth2
sudo ip netns exec isp ip route add 10.1.1.1/32 dev eth0
sudo ip netns exec isp ip route add 10.25.1.65/32 dev eth1
sudo ip netns exec isp ip route add 10.25.1.66/32 dev eth2
sudo ip netns exec isp ip route add default via 10.1.1.1

# Second, down in the direction of the example.com machine room.

sudo ip netns exec backbone ip addr add 10.1.1.1/32 dev eth1
sudo ip netns exec backbone ip route add 10.130.1.1/32 dev eth1
sudo ip netns exec backbone ip route add 10.130.1.0/24 via 10.130.1.1

sudo ip netns exec example ip addr add 10.130.1.1/32 dev eth0
sudo ip netns exec example ip route add 10.1.1.1/32 dev eth0
sudo ip netns exec example ip route add default via 10.1.1.1

# Configure the LAN behind each broadband modem.

sudo ip netns exec modemA ip addr add 10.25.1.65/16 dev eth0
sudo ip netns exec modemB ip addr add 10.25.1.66/16 dev eth0

for modem in modemA modemB
do
    sudo ip netns exec $modem ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev eth1
    sudo ip netns exec $modem ip route add default via 10.25.1.1
    sudo ip netns exec $modem iptables --table nat \
        --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
done

for host in h1 h2 h3 h4
do
    n=${host#?}
    sudo ip netns exec $host ip route del default
    sudo ip netns exec $host ip addr add 192.168.1.1$n/24 dev eth1
    sudo ip netns exec $host ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
done

# Configure the 10.130.1.* network that the example.com machines share.

sudo ip netns exec example ip addr add 10.130.1.1/24 dev eth1
sudo ip netns exec ftp ip addr add 10.130.1.2/24 dev eth0
sudo ip netns exec mail ip addr add 10.130.1.3/24 dev eth0
sudo ip netns exec www ip addr add 10.130.1.4/24 dev eth0
for name in ftp mail www
do sudo ip netns exec $name ip route add default via 10.130.1.1
done
```

Here's what I would want to do :

> I want my Ubuntu base machine to be a part of the same infrastructure itself (at the same level as one of the h1/h2/h3/h4 boxes) such that I can directly access all the other boxes on the infrastructure via SSH and also directly access the services running on them. 
>   So for example, as of now I can access (ping for example)
>   www.example.com from inside  any of the boxes h1/h2/h3/h4, but not
>   directly from the base Ubuntu box. I want to be able to do this
>   directly from the base Ubuntu box, without having to first ssh into
>   one of the h1-h4 boxes and then do it.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the subnet range of the ip the h1-h4 have, you are able to ssh to them directly because i assume you're ip is also in the same range (192.168.1.x).

you can try changing you're **ip** to 10.130.1.x and try ssh into the other servers but but doing this you won't be able to ssh directly into h1-h4, you have to go through the **ISP** and **ModemA** or **ModemB**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this won't really work. Apologies for having the question a little unclear. Have made the required changes to the question. Hopefully, it makes better sense now.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps that make those four hosts `h1` through `h4` accessible from the main host:

1. When the container is started in `launch.sh`, it is given a port on which it will make its SSH service available to the main host, like:

   ```
   start_container h1 fopnp/base 2201
   ```
2. The `ssh-config` file needs to include an alias that tells SSH, when the hostname is accessed, to instead connect to localhost on that port:

   ```
   Host h1
     Hostname 127.0.0.1
     Port 2201
   ```

So, to make all of the hosts available in the same way that `h1` and `h4` are available, give them all unique port numbers in their `start_container` lines, and then create host aliases for them in the SSH file. Good luck!